# Why does the read() block in this case?(linux epoll)

Tags: c, linux, unix, io, epoll

I am new to `unix programming` and today I am trying `epoll` but getting stuck in a problem.

Under `level-triggered` mode, I think each new input event including `Ctrl-D` will cause `epoll_wait` to return. It works fine. But when I type somethings like `aaa`, follow with `Ctrl-D`, `read` blocks. When I type `Ctrl-D`, it doesn't.

Could you please explain what happens?

And should I read off all data when `epoll_wait` is done and according `fd` is ready？

Thanks!

```
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    // create event
    struct epoll_event stdin_ev, events[10];

    // set event
    stdin_ev.events = EPOLLIN;
    stdin_ev.data.fd = STDIN_FILENO;

    // create epoll
    int epfd = epoll_create(1), i, rcnt;
    char c;

    // set monitoring STDIN_FILENO 
    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, STDIN_FILENO, &stdin_ev);

    while(1) {
        int ret = epoll_wait(epfd, events, 1, 1000);

        // timeout or failed
        if(ret == 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "timeout\n");
            continue;
        } else if (ret < 0) {
            perror("ret<0");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // readable
        fprintf(stdout, "%d event(s) happened...\n", ret);
        for(i=0; i < ret; i++) {
            if(events[i].data.fd == STDIN_FILENO &&\
               events[i].events&EPOLLIN) {
                // read a char
                rcnt = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1); 
                // if read 0 char, EOF?
                if(rcnt != 1) {
                    fprintf(stdout, "read %d byte\n", rcnt);
                    continue;
                }
                // else print ascii
                fprintf(stdout, "ascii code: %d\n", c);
            }
        } 
    }
    close(epfd);
    return 0;
}
```

input: `aaa`+`Ctrl-D`, result:

```
timeout
aaa // <-- `aaa`+`Ctrl-D`
1 event(s) happened...
ascii code: 97
1 event(s) happened...
ascii code: 97
1 event(s) happened...
ascii code: 97
1 event(s) happened...
^C // <-- read block here, `Ctrl-C` to kill
```

Then I try setting `STDIN_FILENO` to be nonblocking and I find that `epoll_wait` still tells there is a readable event although `read()` returns -1. But if I just type `Ctrl-D`, `read()` return 0.

```
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int set_nonblock(int sfd) {
    int flags, s;
    flags = fcntl(sfd, F_GETFL, 0);
    if(flags == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        return -1;
    }
    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    s = fcntl(sfd, F_SETFL, flags);
    if(s == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    // create event
    struct epoll_event stdin_ev, events[10];

    // set event
    stdin_ev.events = EPOLLIN;
    stdin_ev.data.fd = STDIN_FILENO;

    // create epoll
    int epfd = epoll_create(1), i, rcnt;
    char c;

    // set nonblocking
    if(set_nonblock(STDIN_FILENO) != 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };

    // set monitoring STDIN_FILENO 
    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, STDIN_FILENO, &stdin_ev);

    while(1) {
        int ret = epoll_wait(epfd, events, 1, 1000);

        // timeout or failed
        if(ret == 0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "timeout\n");
            continue;
        } else if (ret < 0) {
            perror("ret<0");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // readable
        fprintf(stdout, "%d event(s) happened...\n", ret);
        for(i=0;i < ret;i++) {
            if(events[i].data.fd == STDIN_FILENO &&\
               events[i].events&EPOLLIN) {
                // read a char
                rcnt = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1); 
                // if read 0 char, EOF?
                if(rcnt != 1) {
                    fprintf(stdout, "read %d byte\n", rcnt);
                    continue;
                }
                // else print ascii
                fprintf(stdout, "ascii code: %d\n", c);
            }
        } 
    }
    close(epfd);
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
timeout
1 event(s) happened... // <-- `Ctrl-D`
read 0 byte // <-- read() -> 0
timeout
timeout
aaa // `aaa`+`Ctrl-D`
1 event(s) happened...
ascii code: 97
1 event(s) happened...
ascii code: 97
1 event(s) happened...
ascii code: 97
read -1 byte // `EPOLLIN` still happens.
timeout
^C
```

Comment: Does [Ctrl+D for ending terminal line input](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177661) answer help?

Comment: @neeru thanks! I know that when type `Ctrl+D`, 3 characters(`aaa`) will be sent. So I think `epoll` should return 3 times and print `97` per loop. But what confused me is that it returns 4 times and the last read call blocks.

Comment: I am not an expert in `epoll` but I think that this can be due to the specificity of the standard input. Stdin is not a file like others and it probably confuses `epoll`.

Comment: handle the error event (-1) properly.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath But I don't monitor error event.

Comment: @HayesPan: "read -1 byte"

Comment: @KarolyHorvath OK. What really confuses is that there are only 3 characters(`aaa`) but `epoll_wait` returns 4 times(`EPOLLIN`).

Comment: Tries setting the `O_NONBLOCK`? It is a bad idea to mix file descriptors without `O_NONBLOCK` and async facilities. Spurious wake-ups happen and should be handled (OS bugs, particular device quirks, etc). Blocking file descriptors do not allow graceful handling for that.

Comment: @Dummy00001 thanks~ I've tried the `O_NONBLOCK` and it works(nonblock anymore) while the werid behavior of `epoll` still confuses.

Comment: Interesting is that `select` has the same behavior.

Comment: @Marian I really suspect that it may be a specific rule...

Comment: When read() returns -1 : inspect errno. Could be EINTR / EAGAIN.

Comment: @joop. It is EAGAIN. It so happens that CTRL-D is an event for which epoll wakes up. But since its a "signalling" message, and no data, `read` returns -1

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the behavior:

If instead of ctrl-D you type 'ENTER', 4 events are reported as with CTRL-D. We see ascii code:10 for the line feed. With CTRL-D `read` blocks.

CTRL-D isn't signalling EOF but rather flushing out the data so far input. CTRL-D itself being recognized as an event. But actually no data to be pulled out on that
fd. And given that the **socket is blocking**, we end up in case where `read` does not return until another set of events happen.

Now if CTRL-D is the first event, it is recognised with `read` yeilding zero. Signaling a EOF condition. This does not happen if there were something to be flushed.

When you made the socket non-blocking, CTRL-D `read` returns -1, with errno set to EAGAIN. Which means 'no data to be read now. try later'.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual (`epoll_ctl`):

```
EPOLLERR
    Error condition happened on the associated file descriptor.
    epoll_wait(2) will always wait for this event;
    it is not necessary to set it in events.
```

As you can see, error conditions are always monitored.

Comment: The problem is that EPOLLERR is not reported in the example above.